# using ifstream::open "meminfo",fileLen is -1

Tags: c++, linux, ifstream

Below is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory.h>


int main()
{
std::ifstream file;
file.open("/proc/meminfo");
if(file.fail())
    return 0;

file.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
int fileLen = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

char buffer[fileLen + 1];
memset(buffer, 0, fileLen + 1);
file.read(buffer, fileLen + 1);
if(file.fail())
    return 0;

unsigned long long total = 0;
unsigned long long free = 0;
sscanf(buffer, "%*s %llu%*s%llu", &total, &free);
file.close();
return 1;
}
```

In the code ,`fileLen` is -1, but I don't know the reason. If `ifstream` opens a different file, like `1.txt`, the program is correct.
at last,thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The contents of `/proc` are not real files, and hence don't have actual sizes. Do not attempt to get their sizes, but instead simply read and parse them normally.

Answer (score 1):

Because this is not a ordinary file:

> The proc filesystem is a pseudo-filesystem rooted at /proc that contains user-accessible objects that pertain to the runtime state of the kernel and, by extension, the executing processes that run on top of it. "Pseudo" is used because the proc filesystem exists only as a reflection of the in-memory kernel data structures it displays. This is why most files and directories within /proc are 0 bytes in size.

Comment: yes, I should have a better knowledge of linux,thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason could be `/proc/meminfo` is not actually a file. `/proc` does not contain real files, they are just snapshot of the current state of the system.

http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html